# How to identify the exact point of caramelization?

Tags: caramelization

I cant seem to find the point of caramel  for my almonds or any other nut. Its either "grainy" (to much water evaporated) or like the batch I just did, too gooey.

Did this 4 times I believe and never managed to find the sweet spot.

I work with 1/1/0.2 (nut/sugar/water). ratio.

Comment: Are you using a thermometer? What temperature are you cooking your caramel to?

Comment: @AMtwo no therm!

Comment: The only way you'll get consistent results when working with sugar or caramel is to use a thermometer and ensure your caramel is the right temperature. Does this answer your question? [What is the real temperature to caramelize sugar?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/108744/what-is-the-real-temperature-to-caramelize-sugar)

Comment: Thought I'd throw this in here as well: [Caramelization occurs independently of melting](https://www.seriouseats.com/how-to-make-caramel-without-melting-sugar)

Answer (score 4):

"Grainy" doesn't mean "too much water evaporated", it means "it crystallized". For caramelization in a pot on the stove, by the time you start getting any significant caramelization, virtually all the water has evaporated already. You need this to happen *without* the sugar crystallizing.

To prevent crystallization, add a second kind of sugar other than sucrose. Corn syrup is the most common thing to use in the US; invert sugar syrup is more widely available elsewhere.

I personally don't think that a candy thermometer is *crucial* for making caramel (some types of caramel, anyway). But if you're not experienced with the process, it really helps you identify the different stages and see what's going on.